# Updating event restores event relations I just deleted?

Tags: apex, dml, event

I have need to programmatically delete an event relation for an event, then add a new one, then do some updating of the event information, then update the event.

I have ran into some roadblocks:

If I try to handle deleting and adding the event relation after updating the event, I could get an error because the event relation (a resource) may have something else in that time slot (which doesn't matter, the fact it has something else is why I am removing it and adding another resource).

So, I try to remove it before updating the event and adding the new event relation (a resource). But then when I update the event, it restores all the deleted event relations AND keeps the newly added ones...

What is this behavior or restoring event relations I just deleted when the event is updated? I can't find anything that talks about this? Would deleting and adding the event relation in one transaction and then updating the event in another transaction fix this?